# SSRS printing SQL Server 2016

Tags: reporting-services, printing, dynamics-crm, crm

I have an issue on our SSRS 2016 printing from Dynamics CRM application. Reports render correctly, but every time I want to print by clicking the print icon, I am prompted to install the ActiveX print control.

**Note**

As a local admin user, I can install it and I can print, but I have to do it every single time. And normal users do not have that option. Also when I open manage add-ons I can see that it is installed.

Running:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019089) - 13.0.4206.0 (X64) Jul  6 2017 07:55:03   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition: 
Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> 
(Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhXme.jpg)

Comment: Your error image shows SSRS 2014. I would suggest to upgrade to 2016 which renders the report to PDF and there is no need for any Active-X control

Comment: thanks for your replay can you tell me how to 
upgrade it to 2016

Comment: For upgrading your server you 'd better check microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/upgrade-and-migrate-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also for the print control issue,  take a look at this page https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/521467-ssrs-print-requires-user-to-be-administrator-to-install-activex-control